# stop the text check in a Login TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a universal app with C#,in which I have a TextBox for Login,but what I remark is this red line appears when I put a text in the TextBox,so is it possible to delete this line and stop this text checking in the TextBox
thanks for help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx#properties

IsSpellCheckEnabled

Read/write  Gets or sets a value that specifies whether the TextBox input interacts with a spell check engine.

Answer (score 1):

As I consider, you should set the [IsSpellCheckEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isspellcheckenabled.aspx) property to false.

```
<TextBlock IsSpellCheckEnabled = "false">
```